# data flow sdk build fails

Tags: java, maven, sdk, google-cloud-dataflow, maven-dependency-plugin

When I try to build the dataflow sdk from the source cloned from [1], it fails with the following stack trace.
Please help me to get it resolved.

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK

**Full Stack Trace**

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen ...</pluginGroups> -->\n<repositories>... @41:15)  @ /home/minudika/.m2/settings.xml, line 41, column 15
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Parent
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - All
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java Examples - All
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Starter Archetype
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Examples Archetype
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Parent 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent ---
[INFO] Installing /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/pom.xml to /home/minudika/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - All 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:prepare-agent (default) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/minudika/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/jacoco.exec,dumponexit=true,output=file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-test-source (add-java8-test-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Test Source directory: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/test/java8 added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 437 source files to /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/classes
[WARNING] /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/CoderUtils.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/CoderUtils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/View.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/View.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:prepare-agent (default) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/minudika/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/jacoco.exec,dumponexit=true,output=file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-test-source (add-java8-test-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Test Source directory: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/test/java8 added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- avro-maven-plugin:1.7.7:schema (schemas) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-test-source (add-test-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Test Source directory: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/generated-test-sources/java added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (java8-testCompile) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-test-sources) > generate-sources @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:prepare-agent (default) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/minudika/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/jacoco.exec,dumponexit=true,output=file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-test-source (add-java8-test-source) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Test Source directory: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/src/test/java8 added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-test-sources) < generate-sources @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-test-sources) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:report (report) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:/home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:jar (default-jar) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:test-jar (default-test-jar) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Skipping packaging of the test-jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (default) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (bundle-and-repackage) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Excluding com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev19-1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all:jar:0.5.160222 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.5.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:jar:3.0.0-alpha-4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.twitter:hpack:jar:0.10.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:0.12.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-protos:jar:0.2.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:0.2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.3.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.3.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev248-1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:jar:v1-rev7-1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev53-1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:jar:v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:jar:1.4.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.20.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.7 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.auto.service:auto-service:jar:1.0-rc2 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.auto:auto-common:jar:0.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] Replacing original test artifact with shaded test artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar with /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded-tests.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (bundle-rest-without-repackaging) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[INFO] Including com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev19-1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all:jar:0.5.160222 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.5.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:jar:3.0.0-alpha-4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.twitter:hpack:jar:0.10.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:0.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-protos:jar:0.2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:0.2.3 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.0.Beta8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev248-1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:jar:v1-rev7-1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev53-1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:jar:v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:jar:1.4.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.20.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.auto.service:auto-service:jar:1.0-rc2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.auto:auto-common:jar:0.3 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.3.1.jar define 1 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - com.google.auth.oauth2.CloudShellCredentials
[WARNING] grpc-core-0.12.0.jar, grpc-all-0.12.0.jar define 248 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.AbstractReferenceCounted
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.inprocess.InProcessTransport
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer$OutputStreamAdapter
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.ReadableBuffers$BufferInputStream
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder$ScheduledExecutorFactory
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.NameResolver
[WARNING]   - 238 more...
[WARNING] grpc-protobuf-nano-0.12.0.jar, grpc-all-0.12.0.jar define 4 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.nano.NanoProtoInputStream
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.nano.NanoUtils
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.nano.NanoUtils$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.nano.MessageNanoFactory
[WARNING] grpc-netty-0.12.0.jar, grpc-all-0.12.0.jar define 80 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.AbstractNettyHandler
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyClientStream$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.SendResponseHeadersCommand
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyServer$2
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$4
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport$3
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$1$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$FrameListener
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$1
[WARNING]   - 70 more...
[WARNING] grpc-auth-0.12.0.jar, grpc-all-0.12.0.jar define 2 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor
[WARNING] protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar, bigtable-protos-0.2.3.jar define 204 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.UInt32Value$Builder
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.TimestampProto
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$OneofDescriptorProto$1
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$UninterpretedOption$NamePart$1
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$MethodDescriptorProto$Builder
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto$Builder
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$UninterpretedOption$NamePartOrBuilder
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.EmptyProto$1
[WARNING]   - com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$EnumDescriptorProto$1
[WARNING]   - 194 more...
[WARNING] grpc-all-0.12.0.jar, grpc-okhttp-0.12.0.jar define 76 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpSettingsUtil
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.NegotiationType
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.AsyncFrameWriter$12
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.AsyncFrameWriter$WriteRunnable
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.Utils
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder$2
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Huffman$Node
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.okhttp.AsyncFrameWriter$7
[WARNING]   - 66 more...
[WARNING] grpc-all-0.12.0.jar, grpc-protobuf-0.12.0.jar define 4 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils$2
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoInputStream
[WARNING] grpc-all-0.12.0.jar, grpc-stub-0.12.0.jar define 29 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryRequestMethod
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$CallToStreamObserverAdapter
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$EmptyServerCallListener
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.MetadataUtils$2$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.MetadataUtils$1$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.MetadataUtils$2$1$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.MetadataUtils
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$1
[WARNING]   - io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ClientStreamingMethod
[WARNING]   - 19 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Shade+Plugin
[INFO] Replacing /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-bundled-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with /home/minudika/Private/Projects/DataflowJavaSDK/sdk/target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-only (default) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all ---
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all:jar:0.5.160222:compile
[WARNING]    com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.21.0:runtime
[WARNING]    com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.21.0:runtime
[WARNING]    org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[WARNING]    org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:runtime
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.14:test
[WARNING]    org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Parent ............ SUCCESS [  0.278 s]
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - All ............... FAILURE [ 27.965 s]
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java Examples - All .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Starter Archetype . SKIPPED
[INFO] Google Cloud Dataflow Java SDK - Examples Archetype  SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.498 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-07T17:53:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/325M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-only (default) on project google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact maven command and the git commit that you are building? (one way to learn this is by running `git log -n 1`)

Comment: I used the latest git repository.
and the command "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" to build.

However I could resolve that issue as I've described below.
Don't know if it will cause another problem in future though :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have something wrong in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`. I'd start with that.